# Unable to get refresh token google api

Tags: python, google-api

I am trying to get google access token and refresh token in my testing google app, but it's only returning me access token not the refresh token. FOllowing is my code

```
data = {
 "code": xxxxxxxxxx,
 "client_id": xxxxxx,
 "client_secret": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
 "redirect_uri": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
 "grant_type": "authorization_code"
}

access_token_res = req_post(f'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data=data)
access_token_data = access_token_res.json()
```

Can anyone please help me in?

Comment: Use scope offline_access

Comment: Is it an installed client or web client

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - It's web client